# Can not implicitly convert type List<SchoolFee.FeeCollection> to List<Student.FeeCollection> Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

I have `List` called `FeeCollection` on two different locations that is `List<BO.SchoolFee.FeeCollection>` &  `List<BO.Student.FeeCollection>`. When I am assigning `SchoolFee.FeeCollection` object to `Student.FeeCollection` it is showing error. My code

```
 studentObj.FeesCollectionPending = paymentlist;
```

Screenshot of error

[image]

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: A `List<Student.FeeCollection>` is not a `List<SchoolFee.FeeCollection>` - those are two very different types. Therefore you cannot assign between them.

Comment: SchoolFee.FeeCollection and Student.FeeCollection are completely different classes.

Comment: `FeeCollection` list is same on both places with same fields.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 although those two classes have the same fields and even names, they reside in different namespaces, compiler treats them as a separate types because they actually are different.

Comment: To add to @DarjanBogdan comment You will have to write an extension method for converting between the two. Or declare the type in a seperate class.

Comment: You need to define that type in a common namespace (Or) refer them from same namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a`BO.SchoolFee.FeeCollection` looks very similar to a `BO.Student.FeeCollection`, for your compiler they are very different classes.

You forgot to write us the types of both `FeeCollections`. It seems they both implement IEnumerable:

```
class FeeCollection : IEnumerable<Fee> {...}
```

If your FeeCollection does not implement it, consider adding it. People expect it to implement `IEnumerable<Fee>`, possible even `ICollection<Fee>`. It is only a few lines of code.

Once you have implemented the `IEnumerable<fee>`, your destination collection needs a constructor that takes this `IEnumerable<Fee>` as input.

```
FeeCollection(IEnumerable<Fee> fees)
{
    foreach (Fee fee in fees)
       this.Add(fee);
}
```

If you don't want to add the constructor, consider creating a converter function:

I'll write the solution as extension functions, so you don't have to change your original classes Fee and FeeCollections. Besides usage looks like LINQ.
See [extension method demystified](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static Student.FeeCollection ToStudentFeeCollection(this IEnumerable<Fee> fees)
{
      Student.FeeCollection feeCollection = new Student.FeeCollection();
      foreach (Fee fee in fees)
      {
          feeCollection.Add(fee);
      }
      return feeCollection;
}

static Student.FeeCollection ToStudentFeeCollection(this SchoolFee.Collection schoolFeeCollection)
{
     IEnumerable<Fee> schoolFees = schoolFeeCollection;
     return schoolFees.ToStudentFees();

     // or if you don't want to implement IEnumerable<Fee>:
     var studentFeeCollection = new Student.FeeCollection();
     foreach (var schoolFee in schoolFeeCollection.GetFees())
     {
          studentFeeCollection.Add(schoolFee);
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<School.FeeCollection> schoolFeeCollections = ...
// convert every schoolFeeCollection to a StudentFeeCollection:
List<Student.FeeCollection> studentFeeCollections = schoolFeeCollections
    .Select(schoolFeeCollection => schoolFeeCollection.ToStudentFeeCollection())
    .ToList();
```

It could be that even your School fee is not equal to a student fee. You'll need a converter as well:

```
Student.Fee ToStudentFee(this School.Fee schoolFee)
{
    return new Student.Fee()
    {
        Description = schoolFee.Description,
        Amount = schoolFee.Amount,
        DueDate = schoolFee.DueDate,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SISBOLibrary.BO.SchoolFee.FeesCollection` and `SISBOLibrary.BO.Student.FeesCollection` are 2 completely different types despite they have exact same fields. To assign `paymentlist` you need to map `SISBOLibrary.BO.SchoolFee.FeesCollection` to `SISBOLibrary.BO.Student.FeesCollection` as following

```
studentObj.FeesCollectionPending = paymentlist
    .Select(p => new SISBOLibrary.BO.Student.FeesCollection { 
        field1 = p.field1,
        field2 = p.field2,
        //and so on
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or you can use [Automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign list to list. You need to use Select function of Linq or create implicit cast operator

Comment: This is useful information, but really needs a code example to be a full answer.